# Advice on Implementing View-Dependent LOD and Progressive Rendering for Real-Time Visualization

Tags: webgl

I'm working on a project that involves real-time visualization of large datasets to create detailed surfaces from heightmap representations. As I'm relatively new to the field of real-time rendering, I'm exploring techniques to improve performance and responsiveness, particularly focusing on view-dependent Level of Detail (LOD) and progressive rendering strategies, but I am a bit overwhelmed at the moment. I am currently utilizing webgl and a server-client infrastructure.

The goal is to achieve smoother interactions (rotating and zooming) and faster load times by dynamically adjusting the mesh complexity based on the viewer's perspective and incrementally refining the visualization. I'm open to other suggestions that could enhance the visualization performance as well.

I'm currently seeking resources, guides, or any form of literature that could help me understand and implement these techniques, or general best practices.
If you have experience with these techniques or know of any resources that could assist someone new to the field, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you!